# MonoTouch on OS X VM within Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, xamarin.ios, virtual-machine

We're getting into iOS development with MonoTouch. All of our machines are Mac Pros with Windows 7 installed via BootCamp. I'm not crazy about rebooting into OS X just to access the MonoTouch IDE. I'm wondering if it's legal and possible to install OS X on a VM within Windows (if I'm already on Apple hardware, it should be ok, right?). Any other issues with Apple's SDK in a VM (I heard they do some hardware checking of some sort). Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

You can't really run OSX on a VM under windows without going the hacking route. The only way to properly virtualize OSX is to run OSX Server under OSX itself, which is not what you want.

The best option for you is to do what I do: run OSX on your Mac, then use something like VMWare or Parallels to run the Windows you have on your BootCamp as a VM. Works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Eduardo is right, running OSX under non-apple hardware is considered illegal according to [apple's license](http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/MacOSX.htm). Moreover, you may run into some issues when creating your developer's account or sumbitting apps.

However, if you still want go the hack way, you can refer to osx86project or just search google for "how to create a hackintosh".

Comment: That's the thing though, it IS running on Apple hardware! I want to virtualize OS X within Windows on a Mac Pro.